# I don't know how to fix this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, button, carousel

I am not really sure what am I doing wrong in manipulating DOM element for each form field. I am creating an image carousel. I am using previous and next buttons. To go to the next element in the array I am using the class.List property in order to add and remove the "active" part of the class in the HTML. I thinks that's the reason is not working but I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the JavaScript

```
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next");
const galleryImgs = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-img");
let currentlySelected = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", next);

function next() {
  
  galleryImgs[currentlySelected].classList.remove("active");
  currentlySelected++; //currentlySelected=currentlySelected+1
  galleryImgs[currentlySelected].classList.add("active");
  prevBtn.disabled = false; 
}


if (galleryImgs.length === currentlySelected + 1) {
  nextBtn.disabled = true;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="image-gallery">
      <img src="./images/1.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img active" />
      <img src="./images/2.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/3.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/4.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/5.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/6.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/8.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/9.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/10.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/11.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="./images/12.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
      <button disabled="" class="btn prev">Prev</button>
      <button class="btn next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <script src="./gallery.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try this

`const galleryImgs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-img")];`

Your querySelector returns a nodeList, but this it returns an array. So you can select them with their index.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @ncadosch With the spread operator (...) you can spread the node list into an array. In your current code, it's not an array. So you can't get item with their index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about updating the index and is NOT about the array versus nodelist - **document.querySelectorAll nodeLists CAN be accessed via index**.

The problem was around the next button not being disabled when you have progressed to the end of the list - in effect when you are already on the last item and then you click next - there is no item to get the classList of - hence it is undefined.

**The issue is related to the logic about disabling the next button when it is at the end of the nodelist. ... you need to move that logic ito the next() function so that it is diabled when you have selected the last item.**

The following puts a red outline around the active item and you can see that clicking the next button behaves as exected - with each click incrmenting the count and adding the active class to the next item. I have swapped in fluffy kitten images since I don't have acces to the images you are using and didn't like the broken image with alt text look.

I have extended what you are doing - and have added a click-handler and function onto the prev button and similarly - have the logic in there to disable the e previous button if the first item has been reselected,

I would probably do this differently and have one function thst an handle oing up or down - but it is fine to have indiv functions for indiv actions.

Either way - the nodelist approach you used was fine - without the spread operator change - which will not resolve the issue once you have reached the end of the array - or returned to the start of it... :)

```js
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next");
const galleryImgs = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-img");
let currentlySelected = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", next);
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", prev);

function next() {
  galleryImgs[currentlySelected].classList.remove("active");
  currentlySelected++; //currentlySelected=currentlySelected+1
  galleryImgs[currentlySelected].classList.add("active");
  prevBtn.disabled = false; 
  
  if (galleryImgs.length === currentlySelected + 1) {
  nextBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}

function prev() {
  galleryImgs[currentlySelected].classList.remove("active");
  currentlySelected--; //currentlySelected=currentlySelected+1
  galleryImgs[currentlySelected].classList.add("active");
  nextBtn.disabled = false; 
  
  if (currentlySelected == 0) {
   prevBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
outline: solid 1px red;
}

img {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="image-gallery">
      <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/cats/images/slide/188392-850x668-Cute-fuzzy-7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img active" />
      <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/W7TNYR/fluffy-kitten-8-weeks-among-pink-flowers-W7TNYR.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/cats/images/slide/188392-850x668-Cute-fuzzy-7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/W7TNYR/fluffy-kitten-8-weeks-among-pink-flowers-W7TNYR.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/cats/images/slide/188392-850x668-Cute-fuzzy-7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/W7TNYR/fluffy-kitten-8-weeks-among-pink-flowers-W7TNYR.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/cats/images/slide/188392-850x668-Cute-fuzzy-7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/W7TNYR/fluffy-kitten-8-weeks-among-pink-flowers-W7TNYR.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/cats/images/slide/188392-850x668-Cute-fuzzy-7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/W7TNYR/fluffy-kitten-8-weeks-among-pink-flowers-W7TNYR.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/cats/images/slide/188392-850x668-Cute-fuzzy-7.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
      <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/W7TNYR/fluffy-kitten-8-weeks-among-pink-flowers-W7TNYR.jpg" alt="Luna" class="gallery-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
      <button disabled="" class="btn prev">Prev</button>
      <button class="btn next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <script src="./gallery.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```